# Need assistance restructuring an N-Tier MVC/WEB.API app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, n-tier-architecture

Currently have the following N-Tiers:

```
MVC/API UI <-> BLL / DAL / NLL / Model
```

Would like to accomplish the following:

```
MVC/API UI <-> BLL <-+-> DAL <-> Model
                     |
                     \-> NLL
```

I have a class in the DAL to return the context. However when I try and reference this class I get the following error (which is mentioned several times on StackOverflow, however all do not apply to this case):

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Corporate.Web.API.Controllers.SiteAdminAPIController._oDataBaseContext'

The following code is in my DAL for the dbContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Corporate.Web.API.Model;

namespace Corporate.Web.API.DAL
{
    public class DataBaseContext
    {
        public DbContext dbContext()
        {
            Corporate_WebEntities _oContext = new Corporate_WebEntities();
            return _oContext;
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is in my MVC/API controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Corporate.Web.API.Model;
using Corporate.Web.API.DAL;
using Corporate.Web.API.BLL;
...
private readonly DataBaseContext _oDataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext();
private readonly DbContext _oDBContext = _oDataBaseContext.dbContext();
```

1. What do I need to do to get this mess working properly?
2. What am I Missing?

Comment: You can't initialize one field based on the value of another unless they are static. Set the contexts in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing wrong at the following line:

```
private readonly DbContext _oDBContext = _oDataBaseContext.dbContext();
```

(1) instead it should be like following:

```
public class SiteAdminAPIController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataBaseContext _oDataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext();
    private Corporate_WebEntities _oDBContext;

    public SiteAdminAPIController()
    {
         _oDBContext = _oDataBaseContext.dbContext();
    }
}
```

(2) Or make it property like below:

```
private DbContext _oDbContextField;
private DbContext _oDbContext
{
    get{
        if(_oDbContextField == null)
        {
            _oDbContext = _oDataBaseContext.dbContext();
        } 
        return _ODbContext;
    }
}
```

(3) and third and easy option which many people do not recommend is like make _oDataBaseContext.

Replace below line

```
private readonly DataBaseContext _oDataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext();
```

with

```
private static readonly DataBaseContext _oDataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext();
```

**Update**
You also need to update `dbContext()` method's return type.

```
public class DataBaseContext
{
    public Corporate_WebEntities dbContext()
    {
        Corporate_WebEntities _oContext = new Corporate_WebEntities();
        return _oContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do the first option the specific Entity I am after does not show up on the intellisense menu. I think possibly DbContext may not be the correct asignment. What would I need to use to get the correct intellisense for all the Entities?

Comment: I am also getting the following error: Unable to load the specified metadata resource. On my linq statement

Comment: @JohnSchultz yes you need to use `Corporate_WebEntities` instead of `DbContext` as a type. see my updated answer.

Comment: OK, did the change and now I am getting the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' to 'Corporate.Web.API.Model.Corporate_WebEntities'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). Ideas?

Comment: disregard last comment, did a cast and now the entities show up

Comment: @JohnSchultz No you should not cast it is bad practise see the updated answer in update section.

Comment: Cool, no compilation errors, however I am still getting that runtime error.

Comment: Line 173:   var _newSiteSettingsItem = new SiteSettingsItemBrief();
Line 174:
> Line 175:   var _query = from s in _context.SiteSettings
Line 176:        select new
Line 177:        {

Comment: Error: Unable to load the specified metadata resource. On this statement: var _query = from s in _context.SiteSettings select new{ s.SiteID, s.CreatedByID, s.CreatedDateTime };

Comment: @JohnSchultz I think that's not part of this question. :)

Comment: Its OK, the problem was the connection string, but it is working now :). THANK YOU very much for the assist on this part.